# Akamai & firewall logs : allow connections on udp port 3478?

Tags: firewall

In can see in the log of my router/firewall that a lot of connections with source port 3478 and destination port 51164 are blocked.

Those connections are from Akamai and they fill my logs very quickly.

Should I allow those connecitons or deny them?

If I have to allow them, can I safely allow port 3478 udp from any ip ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as what is it:

Could be a couple of things. Normally that protocol/port is for STUN (and also a few games use it).

Aside from that, there is an Akamai download client that uses it, whole discussion on that [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=908665). The Akamai FAQ on 'NetSession Interface' is [here](http://www.akamai.com/html/misc/akamai_client/netsession_interface_faq.html). It's used by Adobe and several anti-virus vendors for updates.

On should you allow it from all IPs:

Probably not. Unless you're doing something that would require it, it's usually better to button down ports you aren't using or specifically allow IPs you want - unless the whole point is to broadly let everybody in, as in a webserver type of scenario.